# Symfony 4, flash messages from repository or somewhere else?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

My situation is this, I want to delete a user record from the database.  This is simple enough to do.  but there are 2 possible outcomes.

1. The user is deleted
2. The user has been **referenced by a FK** and the **delete will fail**, so, the user is marked disabled. (active/enabled = false)

My thoughts are that this action taken against the `Users` entity should be in the `UsersRepository` so that is where my method `deleteUser($user)` is. `$user` being the user object [automatically queried via ParamConverter](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-doctrine/query-reuse-tricks#paramconverter-automatically-querying) and passed to the repository method.

Because the work is done in the repository, that is where it makes sense to me to provide feedback from.

How do I `addFlash()` from my `App\Repository\UsersRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository`? or should I do this "work" elsewhere?

Comment: thanks for the down vote && constructive feedback

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE:
I asked this question a long time ago, while what I figured out below works, as is pointed out in the comments, it is a bad practice.

To answer my question directly, "Some other place" is how to acomplish this.

In the end, this was a simple one-off task, and so all the logic is simply in the controller.  It was never needed to reuse it elsewhere.

However, I have similar situations where the removal of entities is much mnore complex.  For these a service is created and used in the controller.  The resutls of the operations are passed back from the service and then the controller will create the flash message.  This way the service is not tied to the UI requiering flash and a session.

### original answer below

I found the `FlashBagInterface` via console `bin/console debug:autowiring`

So normal dependency injection of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface`

and you can `$this->FlashBagInterface->add()` simple.

for completeness of answer, here is the code;

src/Repository/UsersRepository.php (most code stripped out for compactness)

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

// use ...
use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;

// ...

class UsersRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{

    private $security;
    private $request;
    private $flash;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, Security $security, RequestStack $request, FlashBagInterface $flash)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Users::class);
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->flash = $flash;
    }

    // ...

    /**
     * deleteUser
     *
     * @param Users $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteUser($user)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $user->setEnabled(false);
        $em->flush();
        try {
            $em->remove($user);
            $em->flush();
            $this->flash->add('notice', 'user.manager.user.deleted');
        } catch (ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException $e) {
            $this->flash->add('notice', 'user.manager.user.can.not.delete.disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the weirdest solution I've ever seen, you should not use any flashes inside repositories.

Comment: why?  The work is being done here, so this is where the results 'A' or 'B' are determined.  Hense reporting the outcome.

Comment: SRP violation. Repository acts upon data and should not care about details like that. If you really have such requirement, create an interface `DeletesUserService`, an implementation `DoctrineFlashUserDeleteService` and inject the flash messenger and the doctrine there. Make your  application depend upon the interface. This is called proper OOP, proper responsibility segregation. Injecting session into repository is plain wrong.

Comment: okay, I will read up on SRP - Maybe I'll put the method into my `UserManagerController.php` where currently `delete()` just calls `$repository->deleteUser($user);`

Comment: one more question if I may, What is the Responsibility of the entity Repository? (I thought it was to manipulate the entity) and thanks for the help thus far

Comment: Load collection of entities from the underlying persistence. Eventually also add/remove from the collection. Nothing more. Read about onion architecture if I may suggest.

Comment: Whatever calls your repo should know something went wrong, i.e. catches some exception, and it is in that caller where you'd set a flash, Controller ideally, but Service setting flash is better than repo. Tho your service could let the exception bubble or catch, log, and throw some new exception which your controller catches and then controller can set flash. Flash comes with AbstractController, if you extend that

Answer (score 1):

You should add flash message from the controller as shown in official doc :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Also, if you are new to Symfony, you may want to take a look at how services work cause it's where a lot of your work and methods are gonna end up. if you use Doctrine an action to delete a user in a controller should looks like this:

```
MyAction(User $user){

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($user);
    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash(
        'notice',
        'Your user is now deleted!'
    );
   return $this->redirectToRoute('some_other_route');
}
```

That's a bit 'out of the box' and can of course be improved but you get the idea ... my advise is, get through some official doc, it's qui te easy to get launched :) eventually try to go through Knp symfony4 first courses it's 2-3 hours long and quite useful

Comment: a Repository class is made a service (it is not excluded like Entity)

Comment: unless you have different business logic depending on wich entity you want to delete, i don't see the point of creating a delete method in each repository class when you can access entity manager from controller

Answer (score 0):

[new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-session-service-deprecation)

private $flashBag;

```
public function __construct(
          private RequestStack $requestStack,
)
{
    $this->flashBag = $this->requestStack->getSession()->getFlashBag();

}
        $this->flashBag->add('notice', 'massage');
```